# How to draw a wiggly line in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am searching for a way to draw a Geometric Brownian Motion (GBM) on Illustrator.
Essentially, a GBM looks like a random wiggly line:

[image]

Thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score 3):

`Effect > Stylize > Scribble` will get you close after some adjustment

[image: scribble]

You could also use `Effect > Distort & Transform > Zig Zag` but that doesn't tend to be as random.

You do realize that those paths aren't random but record variations in activity on a given day creating the zig zag path. There's nothing random about them.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to find a stock in google eg [https://www.google.com/search?q=google+stock&oq=google+stock&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.3855j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8](https://www.google.com/search?q=google%20stock&oq=google%20stock&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.3855j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)

and then in the browser inspector copy the svg, paste it into a text file and save eg graph.svg and then open with illustrator

Comment: Thank you @HaydenChambers, your SVG method is pure gold... Frankly I am disappointed in myself for not thinking of that, but alas you did hahaha